# How to insert a variable with two comma seperated values into a variable containing multiple comma seperated values in Bash

Tags: bash

I have two variables i and t. I want to change $i so the second and third comma separated fields (30:20,12:45) are replace with the values of $t to create a new variable $o.

```
i=whatever,30:20,12:45,whenever,NULL
t=12:20,12:40
```

So $o should become:

```
echo $o

whatever,12:20,12:40,whenever,NULL
```

How can this best get done in Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `cut`

```
o="$(echo $i | cut -d, -f1 ),$t,$(echo $i | cut -d, -f4- )"
```

using `awk`

```
o="$( echo "$i" | \
      awk -v vart="$t" 'BEGIN {  FS="," } { print $1 "," vart "," $4 "," $5 ; } ' 
   )"
```

Comment: Thanks EchoMike44 works fine!